# How can I delete the previous pictures which are added by current user while uploading new profile picture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm stuck with these MVC things, How can I delete old profile picture on the upload of new one,

I'm uploading file on the base of sessionId, I know it is not a good Idea but How can I do that,

Here is the way How I upload it, BUT HOW TO DELETE ON NEW UPLOAD of file

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        // pass the dom node (ex. $(selector)[0] for jQuery users)
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
        // path to server-side upload script
        action: '/User/PictureUpload/',
        params: { sessionId: $('#sessionId').val() },
        // file extension
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],

        messages: {
            typeError: "{file} has invalid extension. Only {extensions} are allowed.",
            emptyError: "{file} is empty, please select files again without it.",
            allowedExtensionsError: "{file} is not allowed.",
            onLeave: "The files are being uploaded, if you leave now the upload will be cancelled."
        },
        showMessage: function (message) {
            alert(message);
        }
    });

    //Line for upstairs 
   ///// using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
</script>

   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PictureUpload( string qqfile,string sessionId)
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_data/Files/");
        var file = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            var stream = Request.InputStream;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["qqfile"]))
            {
                // IE
                HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = Request.Files[0];
                if (postedFile != null) stream = postedFile.InputStream;
                file = Path.Combine(path, sessionId);
            }
            else
            {
                //Webkit, Mozilla
                file = Path.Combine(path, sessionId );
            }

            var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message }, "application/json");
        }

        return Json(new { success = true }, "text/html");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to know where the "old/current" picture is stored, and IF the upload succeeds, simply delete the old picture using this here:

```
stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, buffer);
System.IO.File.Delete(string path);
```

Like i said though, you'll have to know before hand what the path of the current picture is...

Comment: I tried but it says ""Access to the path 'C:\Users\jack\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\A MVC Projects\RSSfeeds\RSSfeeds\App_data\Files\' is denied.

Comment: That is most likely because you are running locally inside your Visual Studio... you can also check to see if the file exists first. Now keep in mind that you need the file's actual path (with the filename in it), not just the folder... and since this is a .Net site, i am expecting the pics to be stored on the server, which your application will need to have access rights to the folder in order to add and/or delete from it.